# How to call a nodejs prototype method within redis queue?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue), a priority job queue backed by redis in [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) app.

I want to push a method of an instance to the queue so that it can be directly called when the queue is processed, something similar to as shown below.

This is an example from [Larevel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues)

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send a reminder e-mail to a given user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendReminderEmail(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $this->dispatch(new SendReminderEmail($user));
    }
}
```

I'm a little confused as to how this can be achieved in my node app with Kue.

Comment: AFAIK, Kue only supports arbitrary object data to be pushed onto the queue, not serialized instances of classes. For that, you need to add another layer on top of Kue.